# CSS Modules, React and Overriding CSS Classes

Tags: css, css-modules

I am using a React component library (React Toolbox), which is outputting this class in their Tab component using CSS Modules and Webpack: `label___1nGy active___1Jur tab___Le7N` The `tab` is a className prop I am passing down. The `label` and `active` classes are coming from the library. I want to apply a different set of styles on `active`, something like `.tab.active` where `tab` is referring to the styles I have created and `active` matches the generated selector the library has created but cannot figure out how to do this with css-modules. I need to override this dynamically selector: `.label___1nGy.active___1Jur`.

[image: Browser]

[[image: CSS]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jshOc.png)
[[image: React]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrgIc.png)

Comment: can you show us a small example of your code?

Comment: I guess it would be easier to modify the react toolbox component than to override a dynamically generated classname...
Or you could use the React Toolbox Webpack Loader https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox#customization

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen the loader and certainly plan to utilize it, but I see this happening frequently, and would like to avoid modifying the library. I am wondering if there is some solution that css-modules itself provides to this problem like the `:global` or `compose` keywords

Comment: Usually you would compose the `.active` class from the `.tab` class. But the react toolbox components don't provide the necessary api to set your own `activeClassname` prop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Old post but still relevant, so adding an answer to help those with similar issue

While not inherently possible in CSS modules alone, the author of the react-toolbox library has actually solved this particular problem very nicely

Read their github docs which are more in depth on the subject at https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox#customizing-components

A list of the themeable classes for a particular component is given on the component demo page on their site too

In your case as well as passing a className for tab, you would also create a theme with classes that overrides that desired parts of the default theme and pass that as the `theme` prop. For example something alog the lines of...

MyComponentWithTabs.css

```
.tab {
  color: white;
}
```

MyTabTheme.css

```
.active {
  color: hotpink;
}
```

MyComponentWithTabs.js

```
import styles from './MyComponentWithTabs.css'
import tabTheme from './MyTabTheme.css'

// blah blah...

return <Tab key={index} className={styles.tab} theme={tabTheme} />
```

Under the surface this uses a decorator they have abstracted into separate library [react-css-themr](https://github.com/javivelasco/react-css-themr), I recommend giving that a read too as it explains how the defaults are composed with your overrides in much greater depth, including the different merging strategies they use

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar case, and I solved it like so:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

...

const activeClassName = {};
activeClassName[`${styles.active}`] = this.props.isActive;
const elementClassNames = classNames(styles.element, activeClassName);

return <div className={elementClassNames} />
```

I'm using the `classnames` package to dynamically add the active class based off of the `isActive` prop. Instead of an `isActive` prop you can provide any boolean value.

A more terse way of doing this may be:

```
const elementClassNames = classNames(styles.element, {[styles.active]: this.props.isActive});
```

Answer (score 6):

Using **:global(.classname)** you can override the external classnames.

Even 3rd party library css can be override.

```
:global(.active) {
  color: hotpink;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS modules won't allow you to safely override the active className (largely by design). Really it should be exposed via an API, e.g. 'activeClassName'.

If the maintainers disagree or you need this quick then you can quite easily add your own active className because your implementing component is managing the index state:

```
import {Tab, Tabs} from 'react-toolbox';
import styles from './MyTabs.css';


class MyTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 1
  };

  handleTabChange(index) {
    this.setState({ index });
  }

  render() {
    const { index } = this.state;
    return (
      <Tabs index={index} onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
        <Tab label="Tab0" className={index === 0 ? styles.active : null}>
            Tab 0 content
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Tab1" className={index === 1 ? styles.active : null}>
            Tab 1 content
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: Code is untested.

Answer (score 3):

### Group style loader

You can use the [group-style-lader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-style-loader) to override the style of the components. This loader gives you an easy and intuitive way of override the style of the components.

### Configure the loader

1. Install the loader

   ```
   npm install --save-dev group-style-loader
   ```
2. Configure the loader in your webpack settings

   ```
   module.exports = {
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.css$/i,
           use: [
             'group-style-loader', 
             'style-loader', 
             {
               loader: "css-loader",
               options: {
                 modules: true
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   };
   ```

> You only need to put it, before the `style-loader` or the `mini-css-extract-plugin` loader.

### Override the style of the components

> The next example show as you can to override the style of the Card component from the App component.

You can define the style of your component as you are used to.

**card.css**

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.summary {
  margin-top: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The unique difference is that in the **Card component**, you going to use the `mergeStyle` function to merge the custom style with the default style of the component.

**card.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mergeStyle } from './card.css';

export function Card({ customStyle }) {

  const style = mergeStyle(customStyle);

  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <div className={style.title}>Title</div>
      <div className={style.summary}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur            
        adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then, in the **App component**, to override the style of the **Card component** you need to define the custom style of the Card component using the separator **`_`**. All the classes using this separator going to be grouped in the **card** property of the style object.

**app.jsx**

```css
.title {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;                
  margin: 44px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
}

.card_title {
  color: blue;
}

.card_summary {
  color: green;
}
```

Finally, you only need to pass the custom style of the **Card component** through the `customStyle` property of it.

**app.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from './card';
import { style } from './app.css';

export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={style.title}>Group style</h1>         
      <div className={style.list}>
        <Card/>
        <Card customStyle={style.card}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the previous example, you have two **Cards components**, the first uses its default style, and the second uses the customs tyle that we have defined.

You can see a full explanation of how to use the `group-style-loader` in its [repository](https://github.com/david-minaya/group-style-loader).

Answer (score -1):

trick in fileName.css

add className-active after declaring className

```
.className{
  background: white;
}

.className-active{
  background: black;
}

<div className={'className className-active'} />
<div className={'className-active className'} />
```

divs always will be black